# Why do my numbers not match, multivariate t distribution in R mvtnorm

Tags: r, distribution, correlation

I was trying to program the algorithm for the cdf for the multivariate t-distribution following Genz and Bretz, The reference package in R is mvtnorm.

When I was testing my function, I found that my numbers don't match up. In the following example, adjusted from the mvtnorm help, the multivariate t random variable has independent components. So the integral should be just the product of 3 independent probabilities

```
> lower <- -1
> upper <- 3
> df <- 4
> corr <- diag(3)
> delta <- rep(0, 3)
> pmvt(lower=lower, upper=upper, delta=delta, df=df, corr=corr)
[1] 0.5300413
attr(,"error")
[1] 4.321136e-05
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```

The reported error is 4e-5, the error compared to the product of independent probabilities

```
> (pt(upper, df) - pt(lower, df))**3
[1] 0.4988254
```

is

> 0.5300413 - 0.4988254 = 0.0312159

I'm getting discrepancies in my own code compared to R mvtnorm for various examples in about the same range.

I'm mostly a beginner in R. So, what am I doing wrong or what is wrong?

(I'm not signed up on a R-help mailing list, so I try here.)

UPDATE: As pchalasani explained, my statistics was wrong, the bug in my own code was in some helper function not in the t distribution code. 
A good way of seeing that being uncorrelated does not imply independence, is looking at the conditional distribution.
Here are the column frequencies %*100 for independent a bivariate random variable (10000 samples) for quartiles (distribution conditional on column variable).

bivariate uncorrelated normal variates

```
([[26, 25, 24, 23],
  [24, 23, 24, 25],
  [24, 27, 24, 24],
  [24, 23, 26, 25]])
```

bivariate uncorrelated t variates

```
([[29, 20, 22, 29],
  [20, 31, 28, 21],
  [20, 29, 29, 20],
  [29, 18, 18, 29]])
```

The distribution in the first and last column is very different from the middle columns.
(Sorry, no R code, since I don't know how to do this quickly with R.)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you are doing. Running pmvt() for the 1-dimensional case looks OK; for the 2-dimensional case [pmvt(lower=rep(lower,2),upper=rep(upper,2),df=df)] gives 0.6429955 with a nominal error of 1e-15, while (pt(upper,df)-pt(lower,df))^2 is 0.6289736. Does your code give answers that match the product of independent t distributions? I agree a bug seems unlikely -- could there possibly be something in the definitions you're missing? If you get no more answers here I would try the maintainer [maintainer("mvtnorm")]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zero Correlation does *not* imply independence, for jointly non-Gaussian distributed random variables!

Let me elaborate: there is no bug here. The flaw lies in your assumption that when the multivariate Student-t random variables are *uncorrelated*, they are also *independent*, which is definitely not the case: the only class of multiavariate distributions where no correlation implies independence, is the MV Gaussian distribution.

To see that two uncorrelated random variables that jointly follow a MV Student-T distribution are not independent, consider the case of `n=2`:

```
require(mvtnorm)
x <- rmvt(100000, sigma = diag(2), df=4, delta = rep(0,2) )
```

Now each column of `x` represents realizations of the two random variables. We first check that their correlation is fairly small:

```
> cor(x[,1], x[,2])
[1] -0.003378811
```

However the correlation of the *squares* of `x[,1]` and `x[,2]` is as high as 30.4%, i.e., definitely *not zero*, proving that `x[,1]` and `x[,2]` are not statistically independent:

```
> cor(x[,1]^2, x[,2]^2)
[1] 0.3042684
```

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer it took me a while to convince myself that you are right. My intuition for spherical distributions and nice ball shaped scatter plots can be pretty wrong.

Comment: And after I stopped worrying about the t-distribution, I found the bug in my program and can now match the mvtnorm results.

Comment: I read pchalasni's reply and upvoted it. I would also suggest that you add edits to your question demonstrating what you later did to resolve your confusion. I, for one, would not have expected the two methods to agree, but maybe you have discovered something instructive.

Comment: @user333700 you're welcome, glad you figured it out. I was trying to think of a quick graphical way to demonstrate that the two random variables are not independent, but couldn't come up with something compelling.